# Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, thin

While passing a string with special character i am getting Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails error. The error in log as follows.

My Request:

```
 http://localhost:3000/search/%
```

Error Log:

```
 Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What could be the problem? Please suggest me an idea to fix this issue.

How to redirect to another page while getting below error?

[image]

Comment: You should escape percent symbol in URL.

Comment: If the user enters in url i need to redirect to any error page, how to do that?

Comment: depending on the error, you can redirect to some page. Suppose `404` is page not found error then in routes you can `match '/404', to: 'controller_name#page_not_found', via: :all` and create a page with that name `page_not_found` and method in that controller `page_not_found`

Comment: I am getting Bad Request error.

Comment: that is `400` error code, `match '/400', to: 'controller_name#page_not_found', via: :all`

Comment: thats not working. Please see the screen shot in my updated question.

Comment: see this https://coderwall.com/p/iumbag/quickly-enable-middleware-based-custom-exception-handling-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your nginx configuration file  as below and create 400.html file in public folder.

server 
   {
      listen 80;

```
  root /public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!

error_page 400 /400.html;
location = /400.html {
    internal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`%` is a special character in url's, and is used for [url-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)
You should use another wildcard symbol, like `*` 
http://localhost:3000/search/*

Answer (score 0):

There are number of exceptions which are raised to handle such errors.
like `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. But this are model exceptions.
With controller we have `ActionController::RoutingError` `ActionController::BadRequest` which are related to routing, mapping url

So when you get `400` error it's a `bad request error`, So you have to handle it with calling a method which will render an html page in response

Try this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :route_not_found_error
    rescue_from ActionController::BadRequest, :with => :bad_request_error
    resue_from StandardError, :with => :render_server_error

    protected
       def route_not_found_error
          render "shared/404", :status => 404
       end

       def bad_request_error
          render "shared/400", :status => 400
       end

       def render_server_error
          render "shared/500", :status => 500
       end
end
```

Add pages your `404.html`, `400.html`, `500.html` in app/views/shared

Comment: yes @Sontya. First of all the control is not coming inside our routes itself. I guess the problem is with thin.

Comment: @poojaagarwal - Sorry but I don't have much idea about `thin` server