# How to redirect on `Invalid HTTP format`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

When I enter some crap (like `http://localhost:3000/?sdasd%asdasd%asd`) in the url of my web app I get:

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    /Users/Pawel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@foo/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:4:in `require'
    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I redirect to the root when this error occurs? I'm using Phusion Passenger.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @MaxWilliams `rescue_from` what?

Comment: I beg your pardon, i thought this was occurring in the controller but if you want to handle it at the http server level then this won't work.  This relates to nginx: i don't know what your downstream http server is.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031526/invalid-request-invalid-http-format-parsing-fails-in-rails

Comment: @MaxWilliams The problem is it seems it does not even get to controller. The http server is nginx but is doesn't get there either - the error occurs in rails and a client get 500 error. `rescue_from` would be fine, but I don't know what to catch - there is not exception thrown.

Comment: Ah then that last link i put in my previous comment, which relates to handling the problem in nginx, should be what you're after.

Comment: Btw, if it occurs in rails it's occuring in the controller.  Everything in rails happens in the controller.

Comment: @MaxWilliams If I enter `/asd%asd` I get nginx `400 bad request`. However, at `/?asd%asd` (with question mark) I doen't get nginx 400 error - I get `500 error` and the backtrace does not even get any controller.

Comment: In the first example, the illegal string is part of the path, and in the second the illegal string is part of the parameters.  That's why you're getting different kinds of errors, i suspect.